# Android show multiple values from input in one layout

Tags: java, android, layout, view

i'm new to android development.

What i want to do is show the 5 variables in one single layout.
I get those variables from the user by input.

I can show up one variable for example ip by setContactView

`setContentView(ipView);`

but how is it possible to show 3-4-5 variables?
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_attempt_view);`

By using the above i understand that i'm calling the layout.
Does that mean i have to form the layout according to the items `id`'s that i'm giving the inputs??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your question but you design your `layout` according to your needs. If you need to show 5 different pieces of input then you might create 5 different `TextViews` in `activity_login_attemp_view.xml` (which is a very long name, BTW, but ok). Maybe something like

```
<LinearLayout
    ...>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" 
    .../>
<TextView 
    .../>
<TextView 
    .../>
<TextView 
    .../>
<TextView 
    .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

where the "..." is your properties such as `height`, `width`, `id`, etc... Then you only call `setContentView()` one time. Then use something like

```
 TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
 tv1.setText(someString);
```

be sure to initialize your `Views` such as with `tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);` **after** calling `setContentView()` or it will `return null`.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, you create a layout which contains many textviews, and call setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); from your activity.

and then use (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ip_id).setText("some string");

Comment: int x=5; String xStringValue = x+"";

Comment: or you could use String.valueOf(YOURINT), which is far nicer to read ;)

Answer (score 1):

As has already been stated, you can create a "View" with as many elements on it as required. Each of these elements will be given an `id` value, whether it be the default, or one set by yourself.

The call to `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);` informs android that you want to display whatever is defined in the layout file you specify as the argument.

For further research, you may want to look at: `findViewById()` - as that is what you'll be using mostly in code, to update your views.

For example, if you wanted to update the text of a `TextView`, you'd use something like this:

```
TextView someText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
someText.setText("Hello!");
```

Of course, you're not limited to string literals in TextView's:

```
int x = 10;
TextView someText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
someText.setText(String.valueOf(x));
```

Hope this helps!